# Can I turn a list or dictionary to a String list in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, string

**List to String**

I want to make something like there’s a list `[123]` and I want it to be `"[123]"` using code in Swift. Do you have any idea?

My tries:

**Attempt One**

```
String([123]) // error: expression not clear because of not enough content
```

**Attempt Two**

```
[123] as! String // error: unknown error
```

**Dictionary to String**

I have a dict like `["123":["123:"123"]]` and I want it to be string, like this: `"["123":["123":"123"]]"`

Dictionary Type: `Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>>`

I tried using

- `String()` initializer
- `as! String!`
- `as! String`
- `as? String?`

But these don't work.

I will thank you very much if your answer is helpful :D

Comment: Are keys and values in this dictionary of String type? Please paste in working Swift code with a proper formatting.

Comment: I entered my dictionary type in my post now, it is Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, String>>

Comment: Are you looking for JSON? Then, have a look a `JSONSerialization`?

Comment: `let json = try JSONEncoder().encode(dict)`

Comment: swiftui doesn’t let us use try function ( app is built by swiftui package )

Comment: Use string interpolation `"\(array)"` and `"\(dict)"`.

Comment: @Doggy Just encode your dictionary `let json = try JSONEncoder().encode(dict)` and then you can convert the json data to String. `String(data: json, encoding: .utf8)`  // `"{"123":{"123":"123"}}"`

Comment: @vacawama I think OP posted the wrong expected result

Comment: I tried, and error

Comment: @Doggy What could you do with this string, once you have it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it easily with [`joined()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/joined(separator:)-7uber) method. First, you will also need to map your array elements to string.

```swift
print("[" + [123].map(String.init).joined() + "]")
// prints "[123]"
```

And with more items in the array:

```swift
print("[" + [1, 2, 3].map(String.init).joined(separator: ", ") + "]")
// prints "[1, 2, 3]"
```

You can customise the output to your needs with `separator` parameter.

```swift
print("[" + [1, 2, 3].map(String.init).joined(separator: "") + "]")
// prints "[123]"
```

Additional Resources:

- [`ListFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/listformatter) in Apple Documentation
- ["Formatter" from NSHipster Blog](https://nshipster.com/formatter/#listformatter), section on ListFormatter.

Dictionaries Question:

Here is a solution for your dictionary problem, with this code you should be able to modify it to your needs.

```swift
extension String {
    var wrappedInBrackets: String { "[" + self + "]" }
}

extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == String {
    var formatted: String {
        map { $0.key + ": " + $0.value }
            .joined(separator: ", ")
            .wrappedInBrackets
    }
}

extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == [String: String] {
    var formatted: String {
        map { $0.key + ": " + $0.value.formatted }
            .joined(separator: ", ")
            .wrappedInBrackets
    }
}

print(["a": ["b": "c"]].formatted)
// prints "[a: [b: c]]"
```

Comment: oh i see, let me use it in my project :DDDD

Comment: @Doggy if this answers your question (and it should) then you should click the checkmark to accept it. (voted.)

Comment: I edited my post, please solve my newest problem ( see “Dictionary to string” that topic ) <- just scroll down then you can see it :DDDD

Comment: @Doggy Once an original questions is answered, you should create a new questions for any other problem you are having.

Comment: But I don’t have enough repulution, every 90 min i can post 1 post

Comment: I have updated my answer with a solution

Comment: nice answerrr, USEFUL!

Comment: Actually we can use String.describing in the list to string topic ( according to the second post by Duncan C )

Comment: I see it now: OP's next question is how to decode this ad-hoc serialization format from a string back into an array or dict. Don't do this. Use an existing standardized format.

Comment: Alexander has a good point. Also these answers are for DISPLAYING arrays/dicts. You should NOT try to write your own methods for converting arrays/dictionaries back and forth to strings.

Comment: Agreed, as I understand the OP was asking for a solution to display the data structures, not encode them to JSON.

Answer (score 3):

Witek's answer is good, and gives you lots of control over the output.

For completeness, another option is the `String(describing:)` function. In the case of an array of `Int`s, it gives the same output:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3]
print(String(describing: array))
```

That outputs

> [1, 2, 3]

### Edit:

`String(describing:)` also works for dictionaries.

This code:

```
let dictionary = [1: "woof", 2: "snort", 3: "Grunt"]
print(String(describing:dictionary))
```

Outputs:

> [2: "snort", 3: "Grunt", 1: "woof"]

(Dictionaries are unordered, so the output does not preserve the order of the original input.)

Comment: Duncan C, your answer is helpful for my old topic ( list to string ), I edited my post now, please solve my newest problem ( dictionary to string ) <- scroll down my post to see it

Comment: @Doggy, the `String(describing:)` function works for Dictionaries as well.